# Localizar e Copiar linha da planilha para formulário, alterar campos e gravar na mesma planilha com novo ID

Tags: vba, formulário, excel-vba

A minha dúvida ė a seguinte: desenvolvi um formulário em VBA  com 20 campos, que faz o registo na planilha BDados, inserindo Também um ID.
O que pretendo é localizar e Copiar um registo da planilha para o formulário, preenchendo  todos seus campos depois alterar alguns deles e gravar na BDados com novo ID.

No Excel será o mesmo que copiar uma linha ,  colar numa nova linha e fazer a alteração do ID e de algumas células.

Resta acrescentar Que o ID está a sr inserido automáticamente quando se abre o formulário.

Sou um leigo no VBA Excel e ainda não consegui encontrar um exemplo que me sirva de inspiração para o meu projecto.

Obrigado. Pela ajuda.

O CÓDIGO JÁ DESENVOLVIDO É O SEGUINTE:

```
Private Sub BTN_GRAVAR_Click()

Dim NR As Long
Dim DATA_MATRICULA As Date
Dim DATA_INICIAL As Date
Dim DATA_FINAL As Date



    Folha2.Select

    Range("A3").End(xlDown).Select

    NR = ActiveCell.Row

    Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = LBL_NR.Caption
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtident.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtmatricula.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtdata.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = txtcilindrada.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = txtpeso.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Cbocombustivel.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = cbolugares.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = cbotipo.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = cbocategoria.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = txtpneuf.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = txtpneut.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = cboseguradora.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = txtapolice.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value = txtvalorizacao.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value = txtinicial.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Value = txtfinal.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = Txtvalor.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value = txttaxa.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Value = cbocentro.Text




    Columns("A:T").AutoFit



    txtident.Text = ""
    txtmatricula.Text = ""
    txtdata.Text = ""
    txtcilindrada.Text = ""
    txtpeso.Text = ""
    Cbocombustivel.Value = ""
    cbolugares.Value = ""
    cbotipo.Value = ""
    cbocategoria.Value = ""
    txtpneuf.Text = ""
    txtpneut.Text = ""
    cboseguradora.Value = ""
    txtapolice.Text = ""
    txtvalorizacao.Text = ""
    txtinicial.Text = ""
    txtfinal.Text = ""
    Txtvalor.Text = ""
    txttaxa.Text = ""
    cbocentro.Value = ""


    Me.LBL_NR = Folha2.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    txtident.SetFocus


End Sub
Private Sub BTN_Sair_Click()

   Unload Me

End Sub







Private Sub txtdata_Change()
If Len(Me.txtdata.Text) = 2 Then
        Me.txtdata.Text = Me.txtdata.Text & "/"
        Me.txtdata.SelStart = 4
    ElseIf Len(Me.txtdata.Text) = 5 Then
        Me.txtdata.Text = Me.txtdata.Text & "/"
        Me.txtdata.SelStart = 7
    ElseIf Len(Me.txtdata.Text) = 10 Then
        Me.txtcilindrada.SetFocus
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub txtinicial_Change()

If Len(Me.txtinicial.Text) = 2 Then
        Me.txtinicial.Text = Me.txtinicial.Text & "/"
        Me.txtinicial.SelStart = 4
    ElseIf Len(Me.txtinicial.Text) = 5 Then
        Me.txtinicial.Text = Me.txtinicial.Text & "/"
        Me.txtinicial.SelStart = 7
    ElseIf Len(Me.txtinicial.Text) = 10 Then
        Me.txtfinal.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtfinal_Change()
If Len(Me.txtfinal.Text) = 2 Then
        Me.txtfinal.Text = Me.txtfinal.Text & "/"
        Me.txtfinal.SelStart = 4
    ElseIf Len(Me.txtfinal.Text) = 5 Then
        Me.txtfinal.Text = Me.txtfinal.Text & "/"
        Me.txtfinal.SelStart = 7
    ElseIf Len(Me.txtfinal.Text) = 10 Then
        Me.Txtvalor.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub txtmatricula_Change()

If Len(Me.txtmatricula.Text) = 2 Then
        Me.txtmatricula.Text = Me.txtmatricula.Text & "-"
        Me.txtmatricula.SelStart = 4
    ElseIf Len(Me.txtmatricula.Text) = 5 Then
        Me.txtmatricula.Text = Me.txtmatricula.Text & "-"
        Me.txtmatricula.SelStart = 8
    ElseIf Len(Me.txtmatricula.Text) = 8 Then
        Me.txtdata.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Me.LBL_NR = Folha2.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Inclua em sua pergunta o código do que você já conseguiu fazer.

Comment: Sugiro quebrar sua pergunta em várias menores ( [MVCE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ). E explicar exatamente o que é cada variável, por exemplo se `txtdata` é um `TextBox`? E qual exatamente é o problema que você está encontrando e que este código não funcionou.

Comment: O código funciona. O formulário regista perfeitamente na tabela BD. O que não estou a conseguir fazer, é localizar um registo já gravado, copiá-la para o formulário, e depois de alterar alguns campos, voltar a registá-lo como novo registo, com novo ID nr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Exemplo

Como não foi definido um exemplo, os seguintes dados foram utilizados para os testes:

[image: Exemplo]

Este é um exemplo e você deverá alterar para sua aplicação.

### Localizar

Para localizar uma String no Excel há inúmeras maneiras, como:

- [Autofiltro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel)
- [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)
- [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-lookup-method-excel)
- [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel)
- For loop com condicional If (Itera cada valor da BD e compara se é igual ao valor desejado).
- Variant Array, Scripting.Dictionary ou Collection.

E outras maneiras extras para refinar a busca, como as Expressões Regulares.

O mais rápido é a utilização de Arrays (Variant Array, Scripting.Dictionary ou Collection), pois diminui a iteração entre o VBA e a planilha Excel, portanto, é a mais recomendada para grandes bases de dados. Porém, a que eu considero mais fácil é o Método Find. Portanto, este será utilizado em conjunto com o exemplo da referência oficial.

[Comparação entre 3 métodos para a análise de performance (inglês)](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)

#### Código

Este código procura na coluna A, pela string `strFind` desde o primeiro até o último valor encontrado. Depois realiza uma ação cada vez que encontra o valor definido.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabela BD")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
strfind = "A2"
With ws.Range("a1:a" & LastRow)
    Set cellFound = .Find(strfind, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
        Do
            'Realiza Ação
            Debug.Print cellFound
            Debug.Print cellFound.Address
            Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
        Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
```

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado Localizar]

Em que retorna `cellFound` que é a string `A2` e `cellFound.Address` que é o endereço de cellFound.

### Formulário

Foi criado um formulário de exemplo:

[image: Formulário Exemplo]

#### Código Localizar

Inserir um código para localizar num botão:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'Define o nome da planilha utilizada
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabela BD")
    'Última linha
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'String a procurar
    strfind = TextBox5.Value
    'Range a ser procurado (Coluna A)
    With ws.Range("a1:a" & LastRow)
        Set cellFound = .Find(strfind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
            Do
                'Realiza Ação
                TextBox1 = cellFound.Offset(0, 1)
                TextBox3 = cellFound.Offset(0, 2)
                'Encontra o próximo
                Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
            Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

E o resultado é, digitando "A5" em Texbox5:

[image: Resultado localizar]

#### Código Novo Registro

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    'Define o nome da planilha utilizada
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabela BD")
    'Última linha
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Define o Range rng
    Set rng = ws.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
    'Escreve uma ID em A nova, com a string "A" junto com o número da linha de BD
    rng = "A" & LastRow + 1
    'Coluna ao lado direito de rng
    rng.Offset(0, 1) = TextBox2
    'Coluna duas vezes ao lado direito de rng
    rng.Offset(0, 2) = TextBox4

End Sub
```

Este é o formulário de Novo Registro.

[image: Form Substituir]

Este é o Resultado de apertar o segundo botão:

[image: Resultado Substituir]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou aplicar no meu projecto e logo informo se consegui.

Comment: Adaptei o código e acabei por solucionar o meu problema. M.obrigado.