# Codigo VBA para deletar linha

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-office

Galera, eu tenho um código que verifica a linha se há a palavra ou frase e deleta a linha:

```
If Mid(Cells(i, 10), 1, 50) <> "Defeito" Then Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Porém eu na planilha há frases como "Defeito + banda larga" ou "Defeito tv", gostaria de que o código sempre que verificar que há alguma palavra na frase diferente de "Defeito", por exemplo,"instalação de modem" ou "refeição", ele delete a linha mas deixe as linhas que conter a palavra "Defeito" dentro da frase.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo do dados na tabela, pode ser uma captura de tela

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6uFqEh2

Comment: é esse ai em cima

Comment: no exmplo acima está deletando tudo que for diferente dquela frase, porém eu gostaria que deletasse somente as linhas em que não houver a palavra "Defeito"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consigo pensar em três modos de realizar esta ação:

- Funções Excel para manipulação de String `InStr()` e `Len()`
- Wildcards
- Regex

E maneiras diferentes, algumas mais otimizadas para deletar

## Funções Excel

Um loop normal em cada linha em que dois fatores são verificados na string.

#### InStr

Primeiro se ela contém a palavra "Defeito" com a função [InStr()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function) e o código `InStr(1, ws.Cells(i, 10), "Defeito", 1)`, que retorna 0 se não houver a palavra e diferente de 0 se houver.

#### Len

Depois a função [Len()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/len-function), que verifica o comprimento da String, como a palavra defeito sozinha possui 7 caracteres. Então é verificado se o comprimento é maior do que 7 caracteres.

#### Loop para apagar

Por último se houver a palavra Defeito e se a String for maior do que 7 caracteres, um loop é realizado de trás para frente para deletar cada linha. Este é um processo lento, que para mais do que 10 000 linhas levaria algum tempo.

```
Dim UltimaLinha As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
UltimaLinha = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
For i = UltimaLinha To 2 Step -1
    If InStr(1, ws.Cells(i, 10), "Defeito", 1) <> 0 And Len(ws.Cells(i, 10)) > 7 Then Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next i
```

## WildCard

Duas maneiras de deletar com WildCard:

- Match
- AutoFiltro

### Match

A Função do Excel `Match()` é usada junto com WildCard e deletada por loop.

```
Dim UltimaLinha As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
UltimaLinha = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
For i = UltimaLinha To 2 Step -1
     If Not IsError(Application.Match("Defeito " & "*", ws.Range("J" & i), 0)) Then Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next i
```

### Autofiltro

```
Dim UltimaLinha As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim RangeFiltrar As Range, RangeVisivel As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
UltimaLinha = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
With ws
    'Mostra os dados filtrados
    If .FilterMode Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
    Set RangeFiltrar = .Range(.Cells(1, 10), .Cells(UltimaLinha, "J"))
    RangeFiltrar.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Defeito " & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set RangeVisivel = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 10), ws.Cells(UltimaLinha, "J")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not RangeVisivel Is Nothing Then
    RangeVisivel.EntireRow.Delete
End If

If ws.FilterMode Then
    ws.ShowAllData
End If
```

É usado o Autofiltro com wildcard e depois as linhas visíveis são deletadas, este método é mais rápido do que um loop linha por linha.

## Regex

As Expressões regulares podem ser usadas, em que um [demo no Regex101 pode ser visto](https://regex101.com/r/QHcu2r/2) e a expressão: `Defeito.+`

#### Habilitar o Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

#### Código

Neste código a célula é validada por Regex e depois uma Range não contígua é criada e no fim a range inteira deletada.

Este método é mais rápido por realizar a ação de apagar de uma vez só, do que realizar o loop um por um.

```
Dim UltimaLinha As Long, j As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Dados()
Dim strData As String
Dim rng As Range, nova_rng As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
UltimaLinha = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
'Preenche dados na Matriz Dados

With ws
    Dados = .Range("J1:J" & UltimaLinha).Value2
    Dim objMatches As Object, objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'Regex
    objRegExp.Pattern = "Defeito.+"
    objRegExp.Global = True
    'Executa Regex
    For j = LBound(Dados) To UBound(Dados)
        strData = Dados(j, 1)
        Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(strData)
        If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each m In objMatches
                'Realiza ação para cada combinação encontrada
                'Debug.Print strData
                If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = .Range("J" & j) 'Define o primeiro item da range para não ocorrer erro na função Union
                Set nova_rng = .Range("J" & j)
                Set rng = Union(rng, nova_rng) 'Cria a range não contígua para deletar
            Next m
        End If
    Next j
End With
rng.EntireRow.Delete
```

### Nota:

> Apagar/Deletar dados é muito sensível e complicado, pois eles podem ser perdidos para sempre. Sugiro realizar um backup dos dados antigos e criar uma cópia da planilha/dados para testes.

Comment: Cara na boa, voce é um gênio. o.O

Comment: Para outras maneiras de procurar uma String, ver [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272169/75104)

Comment: Só deu uma duvida, na Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1") eu coloco o nome da minha planilha?

Comment: @typemark isso mesmo, o padrão quando um novo arquivo é criado é Planilha1, por isso uso de exemplo.

Comment: tendi, na mesma linha do codigo, termina em "invalido fora de um procedimento", será que precisa alterar todos os nomes na planilha?  Ou cria-la do zero?

Comment: Somente atualizar para a planilha em que estão os dados utilizados