# Deletar valores indesejados VBA

Tags: vba

Galera bom dia, tenho a seguinte macro para executar um filtro dentro de uma coluna e me trazer um valor determinado.
porem, dentro dessa mesma coluna ha outros valores, gostaria de excluir os valores que nao vou utilizar, como posso fazer?
segue o cod.

```
Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha3")
With ws3
    'Limpa os Autofiltros da Planilha para evitar erros
    If .FilterMode Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
    'Última Linhada colunaE
    UltimaLinhaE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    'Autofiltro
    .Range("E1:E" & UltimaLinhaE).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Cell 01"
End With
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [Codigo VBA para deletar linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297112/75104)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Código

```
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim UltimaLinhaE As Long
Dim RangeVisivel As Range
Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha3")
With ws3
    'Limpa os Autofiltros da Planilha para evitar erros
    If .FilterMode Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
    'Última Linhada colunaE
    UltimaLinhaE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    'Autofiltro
    .Range("E1:E" & UltimaLinhaE).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Cell 01"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RangeVisivel = .Range(.Cells(1, "E"), .Cells(UltimaLinhaE, "E")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not RangeVisivel Is Nothing Then
        RangeVisivel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End With
```

## Explicação

Primeiro os valores diferentes do desejado são filtrados: `.Range("E1:E" & UltimaLinhaE).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Cell 01"`

Depois uma range é definida com os valores das células visíveis: `Set RangeVisivel = .Range(.Cells(1, "E"), .Cells(UltimaLinhaE, "E")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Se existir essa Range, a linha inteira é deletada: `RangeVisivel.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: apresentou um erro 
"Erro em tempo de execução 1004
o Método Delete da classe range falhou"
If Not RangeVisivel Is Nothing Then
        **RangeVisivel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

** = onde esta o erro

Comment: Você possui células mescladas?

Comment: desculpa, possuo sim, mas elas sao essencias para a apresentacao da planilha.... ha outro modo de realizar este filtro?

Comment: Podeira me dar um exemplo?

Comment: tirei as mesclagens e o erro persiste

Comment: Verdade, é possível deletar com células mescladas. Podem ser as alterações realizadas no código. Difícil saber sem entender o código e ver os dados. Tente colocar `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` Antes de deleter e `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` depois de deletar