# Utilizar VBA para apagar linhas com critério determinado por uma célula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, planilha

Preciso de um Vba que faça a seguinte ação:
No momento em que for ativado, leia uma célula específica e apague linhas de uma outra aba levando em consideração a célula específica como critério.
Exemplo:
Na Planilha1 tenho dois produtos:
 
Camisa Azul A 
 
Camisa Azul B 
 
Mas na planilha 2 na célula D2 está escrito somente "Azul". Eu preciso que esse código considere o texto presente na célula D2 da Planilha2 e apague as linhas aonde estão ambas as camisas presentes na Planilha1, considerando apenas a palavra "Azul" presente nos textos dentro das célula.

Utilizo o código abaixo normalmente

```
lLast = Planilha1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For lRow = lLast To 2 Step -1
If _
Cells(lRow, "A") Like "*Critério*" Then
Rows(lRow).Delete
    End If
Next lRow`
```

Mas nesse caso eu não consegui referenciar a célula, se tiver como utilizá-lo como eu faria?

Answer (score 0):

### Exemplo

Assumindo duas planilhas, uma chamada "Planilha 1" e outra "Planilha2".

Os dados estão inseridos em "Planilha1", conforme a tabela a seguir:

```
|   |       A        |
|---|----------------|
| 1 |                |
| 2 | Camisa Azul A  |
| 3 | Camisa Verde A |
| 4 | Camisa Azul B  |
| 5 | Camisa Verde B |
```

E na célula "D2" da "Planilha2" a palavra **Azul**

### Código

```
Dim UltimaLinha As Long, i As Long
Dim ref As String
Dim Rng As Range, nova_rng As Range
Dim ws_ref As Worksheet, ws_dest As Worksheet
Set ws_ref = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha2")
Set ws_dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
'Referência
ref = ws_ref.Range("D2")

With ws_dest
    UltimaLinha = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = UltimaLinha To 2 Step -1
        If Not IsError(Application.Match("*" & ref & "*", .Range("A" & i), 0)) Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = .Range("A" & i) 'Define o primeiro item da range para não ocorrer erro na função Union
            Set nova_rng = .Range("A" & i)
            Set Rng = Union(Rng, nova_rng)   'Cria a range não contígua para deletar
        End If
    Next i
End With
Rng.EntireRow.Delete
```

#### Explicação

- Atribui à planilha de referência `ws_ref`, onde estão as células preenchidas com o critério de referência.
- Atribui à planilha de destino `ws_dest` com o valor da Planilha de referência.
- Atribui o valor de `D2` à variável `ref`
- Encontra a Última Linha da coluna A da planilha `ws_dest`
- Realiza um loop da Última Linha até a segunda, procurando um Match do valor de `ref`
- Cria uma União não contígua com as células dos valores encontrados. A união é criada porque é mais rápido excluir tudo de uma vez do que deletar linha por linha.
- Exclui a linha inteira do intervalo desejado com `Rng.EntireRow.Delete` ou se quiser somente limpar a linha inteira `Rng.EntireRow.Clear`

**Obs.:** Para mais informações de outras formas de realizar isto veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297112/75104)

### Resultado

```
|   |       A        |
|---|----------------|
| 1 |                |
| 2 | Camisa Verde A |
| 3 | Camisa Verde B |
```

### Nota:

> Apagar/Deletar dados é muito sensível e complicado, pois eles podem ser perdidos para sempre. Sugiro realizar um backup dos dados antigos e criar uma cópia da planilha/dados para testes.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela resposta!
No caso o critério que eu preciso para que apague a linha é uma parte do texto da célula, exemplo:
Na Planilha 1 tenho dois produtos:
Camisa Azul A
Camisa Azul B
Mas na planilha 2 na célula D2 está escrito somente "Azul". Eu preciso que esse código considere o texto presente na célula D2 da Planilha2 e apague as linhas aonde estão ambas as camisas presentes na Planilha1, considerando apenas a palavra "Azul" presente nos textos dentro das célula. Seria possível adaptar esse código para essa utilização?

Comment: Favor, editar a pergunta com estas informações. Criando um [mcve]

Comment: Certo, editado.

Answer (score -1):

```
For Each cell In [Tabela1[Coluna1]]
    If cell = "critério" Then Rows(cell.Row).Delete
Next

For Each cell In Range("A2:A1000")
    If cell = "critério" Then Rows(cell.Row).Delete
Next
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor sua resposta?