# Formatação Condicional entre colunas no VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba, formatação-condicional

Preciso de uma ajuda com a formatação condicional.

Tenho um código VBA para comparar duas colunas, uma que fica em uma aba escondida, contém uma série de sistemas que utilizamos na empresa e outra contém uma coluna onde esses sistemas são mencionados, porém nesta segunda coluna os sistemas podem vir acompanhados com informações adicionais e por isso essa 'validação' acaba não funcionando uma vez que os valores não são exatos.

E.g.:

Coluna A
***HANA_ERA***

Coluna B
***ASIA-HANA_ERA-PRODUCTION***

Vocês têm alguma dica do que eu poderia adicionar ao código abaixo para que essa validação ocorra e a formatação condicional funcione?

```
Sub Sistemas_Criticos()
'
'
'
Dim rng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("_db").Visible = True
Sheets("_db").Select
With Worksheets()
    Sheets("_db").Range("a2", Sheets("_db").Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Select
End With
Sheets("e-Template").Select
With Worksheets()
    ActiveSheet.Range("f8", ActiveSheet.Range("f8").End(xlDown)).Select
End With
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions.DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions.Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions.StopIfTrue = False
    Sheets("_db").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Desde já, agradeço os comentários e sugestões de todos.

Comment: Veja a função [InStr](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) ou condicional com [Operador Like](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada e acho que não é exatamente o que estou procurando. Será que tem algo como 'contains' onde eu consiga declarar uma coluna?

Comment: Veja se [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297112/75104) te ajuda