# Pesquisa de CEP

Tags: vba

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução e surgiu a necessidade de acrescentar a pesquisa de CEP. De retorno gostaria de obter o endereço com base no CEP informado.

Comecei a escrever o código abaixo mas parei nisso.

```
Sub lsPesquisaCEP(ByVal sCEP As String)
    On Error GoTo TratarErro

    Range("Consulta!a1:H1").Clear

    If sCEP <> "" Then
        With ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("webservicecep_Mapa")
            .ShowImportExportValidationErrors = False
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .PreserveColumnFilter = False
            .PreserveNumberFormatting = False
            .AppendOnImport = False
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= _
            "http:/republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=" & sCEP, ImportMap:= _
            Nothing, Overwrite:=False, Destination:=Range("Consulta!$a$1")


    End If

    Calculate

Sair:
    Exit Sub
TratarErro:
    MsgBox "CEP não cadastrado!"
    GoTo Sair
    Resume
End Sub
```

Dá sempre como CEP não cadastrado!

Comment: Você pode pesquisar pelo site dos correios, o problema é que eles bloqueiam para acessos em excesso. Porque eles vendem este serviço, chamado de [DNE](https://www.correios.com.br/a-a-z/dne#tab-2). Então você deve pagar de qualquer forma ou para os correios ou algum aplicativo que presta este serviço. Ou se você encontrar algum site atualizado de CEPs gratuito, pode realizar consultas na base de dados deste site. Ou se possuir uma base de dados de CEPs, pode [localizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272169/75104) com VBA

Comment: Poderiam rever minha pergunta antes de colocar fora de escopo????

Comment: [Duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320718/75104)