# Pesquisa de CEP via Programação VBA

Tags: vba

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução e surgiu a necessidade de acrescentar a pesquisa de CEP. De retorno gostaria de obter o endereço com base no CEP informado. Pretendo usar essa pesquisa para preenchimento de endereço automático apos informar o CEP.

Comecei a escrever o código abaixo mas parei nisso.

```
Sub lsPesquisaCEP(ByVal sCEP As String)
    On Error GoTo TratarErro

    Range("Consulta!a1:H1").Clear

    If sCEP <> "" Then
        With ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("webservicecep_Mapa")
            .ShowImportExportValidationErrors = False
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .PreserveColumnFilter = False
            .PreserveNumberFormatting = False
            .AppendOnImport = False
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= _
            "http:/republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=" & sCEP, ImportMap:= _
            Nothing, Overwrite:=False, Destination:=Range("Consulta!$a$1")


    End If

    Calculate

Sair:
    Exit Sub
TratarErro:
    MsgBox "CEP não cadastrado!"
    GoTo Sair
    Resume
End Sub
```

Dá sempre como CEP não cadastrado!

Comment: Leia [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401/75104)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você informa a URL está faltanto um "/" depois de "http:"

```
"http://republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep="
```

Comment: Poxa...Era isso mesmo! Muito Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!!!