# Retornando valor via VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Criei um banco de dados em Excel que deve aceitar apenas 1 CPF. Assim criei a seguinte função que faz a verificação e impede que cadastros repetidos sejam inseridos.

```
Function verifica_cpf(cpf As Integer) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Long, x As Boolean
cpf = False

intValueToFind = Range("i3").Value

Sheets("Banco de Dados").Select
NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For i = 3 To NumRows
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = intValueToFind Then
        MsgBox ("CPF já cadastrado na linha " & i & vbNewLine & "Dados não inseridos no banco")
        x = True
    End If
Next i

Return cpf   ' Esta linha apresenta o erro de "fim de instrução esperado" ao compilar

End Function
```

Quando o código estava dentro da minha macro principal, funcionava sem problemas. Os erros começaram quando eu migrei ela para uma função separada para ficar mais organizado.

Na sub principal ela é chamada da seguinte maneira:

```
Private Sub Cadastrar()

Sheets("Cadastrar").Select

Dim cpf = verifica_cpf() ' Esta linha apresenta o erro de "fim de instrução esperado" ao compilar
.
.
.
end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função está sendo chamada de forma incorreta e o VBA não utiliza `Return` nas funções. A sintaxe do VBA é um pouco diferente, conforme o código a seguir:

```
Function verifica_cpf(cpf As Long) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long

    Sheets("Banco de Dados").Select
    NumRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To NumRows
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = cpf Then
            MsgBox ("CPF já cadastrado na linha " & i & vbNewLine & "Dados não inseridos no banco")
            verifica_cpf = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    verifica_cpf = False

End Function

Private Sub Cadastrar()
    Dim cpf As Long
    Dim x As Boolean
    cpf = InputBox("Digite o CPF: ")

    x = verifica_cpf(cpf)
    If x Then
        MsgBox ("É Verdadeiro")
    Else
        MsgBox ("É Falso")
    End If
End Sub
```

> **Obs.:** Um loop em cada linha pode ser demorado, há [outras maneiras de localizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272169/75104). Cada uma com performance diferente. O mais rápido é a utilização de Arrays (Variant Array, Scripting.Dictionary ou Collection), pois diminui a interação entre o VBA e a planilha Excel, portanto, é a mais recomendada para grandes bases de dados. Porém, a que eu considero mais fácil é o Método Find.