# Copiar da mesma linha algumas colunas, de todas as planilhas para a planilha inicio (primeira) se atender a critério

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou fazendo um projeto onde preciso que na coluna Q de todas as planilhas seja encontrado a variável `valor procurado`, e, se encontrado esse critério, preciso copiar as colunas de L a Q daquela linha para a planilha inicio.

Tentei de duas maneiras diferentes. Na primeira o erro ocorre na linha do `set i`:

```
    Sub CopiarProgrameAqui()
    Dim i As Range
    Dim primeiraLinha As Integer
    Dim linhaDestino As Integer
        linhaDestino = 1
    Dim plan As Object
    Dim valorProcurado As Double
        valorProcurado = 4.25



    For Each plan In Worksheets
        plan.Select  

        Set i = ActiveSheet.Range("Q:Q").Find(valorProcurado)
        primeiraLinha = i.Row
        Do   
             ActiveSheet.Range("L" & i.Row & ":Q" & i.Row).Copy _
                                inicio.Range("AA" & linhaDestino)                              
            linhaDestino = linhaDestino + 1
            Set i = ActiveSheet.Range("Q:Q").FindNext(i)
        Loop While primeiraLinha < i.Row          
    Next    
    End Sub
```

Desta segunda maneira, ele encontra, seleciona, porém não cola na planilha inicio.

```
Sub copia()

Dim plan As Object
Dim valorProcurado As Double
    valorProcurado = 4.25

Dim ant As Range
Dim contar As Integer
    contar = 1

For Each plan In Worksheets
     plan.Select
     Range("Q1").Select

    Do While contar < 300
        If UCase(ActiveCell) = UCase(valorProcurado) Then
            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy
            Sheets("inicio").Select
            Range("AA1").Activate
            Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlValue

        End If
        contar = contar + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
Next


Sheets("inicio").Select
Range("a1").Select


End Sub
```

Depois de correções e reduzindo a quantidade de células a ser copiadas e coladas,
ficou assim:

```
Sub testecopia()


Dim procurado As Double
    procurado = 4.25
Dim i As Long
    i = 0


For Each plan In Worksheets
    With plan.Range("q1:q500")
        Set c = .Find(procurado, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Endereco = c.Address
            Linha = c.Row
            i = i + 1

            Do


                c.Offset(-1, -4).Select
                Selection.Copy

                Sheets("inicio").Select
                Range("AA" & 1 + i).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste

                i = i + 1

                Set c = .FindNext(c)

            If c Is Nothing Then
                        GoTo DoneFinding
            End If
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
DoneFinding:

    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Alguns problemas no seu código, mas veja como utilizar o [Find nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272169/75104), tente declarar linhas como Long, i.e.: `Dim linhaDestino As Long` e você realiza um loop em todas as planilhas `For Each plan In Worksheets` mas depois usa `Select` e o `ActiveSheet`, pode excluir o `plan.Select` e utilizar o objeto `plan` com `Set i = plan.Range("Q:Q").Find(valorProcurado)`. Tente [evitar o uso de Select e Active](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/7690982)

Comment: Obrigada pelo toque, vou ler sobre a utilização do select e activate sim. Enquanto isso, consertei alguns erros do código e tô conseguindo copiar e colar os dados, porém só do primeiro que ele encontra. Ou seja, o findnext não está dando certo. Vou colocar o código corrigido no post

Comment: Troque `firstAddress` por `Endereco`, veja o link que te enviei, o método Find está sendo utilizado incorretamente.

Comment: E há redundância no seu código, não é necessário o `DoneFinding:`, já que a mesma condição está sendo realizada no while loop. Você pode utilizar o `DoneFinding:` para outras condições e fazer tratamentos de erros...

Comment: ta legal. deu certo aqui, muito obrigada