# Como posso diminuir o tempo de execução na minha aplicação em VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em VBA que é responsável por buscar em uma planilha excel 2 dados em colunas diferentes: o numero de serie, e o inicio de fabricação. Em seguida, eu relaciono com uma tabela em Access e comparo o numero de serie presente no banco de dados, e insiro na coluna INICIO_FBR, o inicio de fabricação vindo do excel.
O problema é que são milhares de dados, e para percorrer toda a tabela do banco de dados esta demorando muito, quando eu uso FindFirst, ou mesmo com um FindNext e depois um FindPrevious, como esta no codigo abaixo.
A pergunta é se tem uma outra maneira de fazer essa busca e essa relação de uma maneira mais rapida? Se sim, como?
Agradeço desde ja!

```
Private Sub Comando9_Click()
 Set db = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ConsultaNSerie", dbOpenDynaset)
 Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'appExcel.Visible = True
 appExcel.Application.Workbooks.Open "K:\EM HP - Comum\Planejamento de 
 Produção HP\CB\Planejamento de Produção_CB_FY19-20\Planejamento de 
 Produção_CB_FY19-20.xlsm"

 Dim Inicio_planejado As Variant
 Dim Numero_serie As String
 Dim SAP As String
 i = 9

 Dim fso As Object
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 Dim Fileout As Object
 Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("K:\EM HP - Engenharia\02-Aplicação\11- 
 Controle de Projetos\Nserie_NoMatch.txt", True, True)

 Do
     SAP = appExcel.Sheets("Disjuntores").Columns("I").Rows(i).Value
     Numero_serie = appExcel.Sheets("Disjuntores").Columns("L").Rows(i).Value
     'MsgBox (Numero_serie)
     Inicio_planejado = 
     appExcel.Sheets("Disjuntores").Columns("T").Rows(i).Value

    If Inicio_planejado <> "" Then
        'MsgBox (Inicio_planejado)
        'quando for vazio, desconsiderar a celula
        'ThisWorkbook.Reg.FindFirst "[OF] = '" + cb_OF.Value + " '"
        db.FindNext "[NUMERO_SERIE] = '" + Numero_serie + " '"
        If db.NoMatch Then
            db.FindPrevious "[NUMERO_SERIE] = '" + Numero_serie + " '"
        ElseIf db.NoMatch Then
            Fileout.Write Numero_serie & "  "
            'MsgBox ("Número de série " + Numero_serie + " não encontrado")
        Else
             'Adicionar o valor de "Inicio_planejado" aos campos na coluna 
      "INICIO_FBR"
             db.Edit
             db![INICIO_FBR] = Inicio_planejado
             db.Update
             db.MoveNext
        End If
 End If

 i = i + 1

 Loop Until appExcel.Sheets("Disjuntores").cells(i, 7) = ""

 Fileout.Close
 appExcel.Quit

 End Sub
```

Comment: Um loop em cada linha pode ser demorado, há [outras maneiras de localizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272169/75104). Cada uma com performance diferente. O mais rápido é a utilização de Arrays (Variant Array, Scripting.Dictionary ou Collection), pois diminui a interação entre o VBA e a planilha Excel, portanto, é a mais recomendada para grandes tabelas. Veja uma [análise de desempenho](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)

Answer (score -2):

O André tem razão, há várias formas de se obter o mesmo resultado cada um com performance diferente, você terá que testar algumas até chegar na melhor performance possível ou satisfatória.

Minha sugestão é :
1-) Importe os dados do Excel para uma tabela temporária, tmpProducao por exemplo.
2-) Faça uma query única com o UPDATE na tabela ConsultaNSerie para alterar o campo INICIO_FBR
3-) Faça outra query com um simples SELECT da tabela tmpProducao relacionado com a tabela ConsultaNSerie para exibir os números de série que não existem

Todas as vezes que precisei fazer algo semelhante, fiz desta forma e sempre obtive uma boa performance.

Abraço